# Прочитать значение по адресу, используемому приложением

Tags: c++builder, winapi, память, c++

Добрый день, я столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Есть выполняемое приложение (*Application*) и мне нужно прочитать значение по известному мне адресу в памяти (*08307AD8*), занятому этим приложением. Для своей программы я получаю привилегии отладчика:

```
OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &th);
LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, "SeDebugPrivilege", &seid);
tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = seid;
tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
a = rl;
AdjustTokenPrivileges(th, False, &tp, sizeof(tp), &tp, &a);
```

И собственно пытаюсь прочитать этот адрес:

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(0, "Application");
if (!hWnd)
{
    MessageBox(0, "Error cannot find window!", "Error!", MB_OK + MB_ICONERROR);
} 
else
{
    DWORD proc_id;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &proc_id);
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, proc_id);
    if (!hProcess)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Cannot open process!", "Error!", MB_OK + MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    else
    {
        BYTE newdata[] = { 0x72, 0x65, 0x64, 0x70 };
        DWORD newdatasize = sizeof(newdata);
        if (WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID) 0x08307AD8, &newdata, newdatasize, NULL)) 
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "WriteProcessMemory is a success!", "Success!", MB_OK + MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Error cannot WriteProcessMemory!", "Error!", MB_OK + MB_ICONERROR);
        }
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
}
```

Выскакивает МесседжБокс **"Error cannot WriteProcessMemory!"**, то есть, как я понимаю, все нормально выполняется до момента обращения по адресу.
Очень прошу помочь мне разобраться что не так здесь, ну или предложите другое более рациональное решение.

Вот область определения переменных:

```
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
LUID seid;
Cardinal rl;
unsigned long a;
HANDLE th;
```

Comment: У меня ОС Windows 7, это может быть важным

Comment: [Здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) пишут, что нужно иметь PROCESS_VM_WRITE and PROCESS_VM_OPERATION.

А GetLastError что говорит ?

Comment: При вызове OpenProcess я использую атрибут PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, что, как я понимаю, предоставляет все права приложению, а не только эти два

Comment: Я думаю, что проблема в том, что вы забыли скопипастить проверку успешного завершения `AdjustTokenPrivileges`.

Comment: Куда скопипастить?

Comment: Я это вижу так: код чтения адресного пространства процесса скопипащен из одного источника, а код запроса отладочной привилегии имеет другое происхождение.

Comment: Нет, здесь все полностью. Причем тут не в лоб скопировано а адаптированно и согласовано. AdjustTokenPrivileges возвращает положительный результат.

Comment: А GetLastError() вызывали ?